# Where is the config file store for the xfce4-plugin "notification area" alias "systray"

Tags: linux, notifications, fedora, xfce, fedora-25

I am on Qubes OS. That means fedora-25 as dom0. I would like to change the configs for "notification area" alias "systray" plugin of xfce. How can I do it. I would like to delete/add one item.
The Gui only gives me the option to hide with ugly arrow on the side or to "clear all known applications". However, regarding the last option I am afraid to lose the notification area as it is and never get it back.
I looked with the "find" command for "xfce4" and "xfce4-plugins" and so on. All the files I could find, e.g. in ~/.config/xfce4, could not help me. I can nowhere find a config file for the plugin.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Known applications is stored as an array in xfconf, in the `xfce4-panel` channel and under the property `/plugins/plugin-[id]/known-items`, where the plugin id is dynamic and depends on the order plugins were added to panel.

You could hack your way messing with `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml` but I strongly advise you not to, instead use `xfconf-query` to read and set values.

I'm going to write down some snippets below so you can use them to craft a script that suits your needs:

```
# Find the plugin id, can be empty if systray is not present
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins -l -v | grep systray | grep -Po "plugin-\\d+" | head -n1

# Get array of current known apps
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/$PLUGIN_ID/known-items | tail -n +3

# Set array of known apps
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/$PLUGIN_ID/known-items -t string -s value1 -t string -s value2 ...
```